# Running Mocha Test - indentation error

Tags: mongodb, automated-tests, mocha.js, meanjs

I am running some mocha tests for a mean.js app and I get a large number of indentation errors and then a "Mocha exploded!" error.

I fixed it this morning but messed with it more and undid my fix by accident. I cannot remember exactly how I fixed it but I was messing with **npm install** and making sure the **mongoDB database** was correct. I checked that my mocha version is up to date which it is.

Any suggestions with what to turn to next that could be the issue would be greatly appreciated.

I attached the terminal errors below.

**Image 1: executing grunt test --force**

[image: Image 1: executing grunt test --force]

**Image 2: indentation errors**

[image: Image 2: indentation errors]

**Image 3: "Mocha exploded!" error**

[image: Image 3: "Mocha exploded!" error]

Comment: The main issue is in the `user.server.model.tests.js` file: there's a syntax error (a curly bracket missing probably?). If you do `node path/to/user.server.model.tests.js` what does it print?
The other error is about some indentation found by `jshint`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was an extra curly bracket in one of the test files that mocha was running through. This solved the mocha exploded issue as well as all of the indentation issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check the poststest script and remove it if necessary.

A script like the below will launch Eslint(a tool that analyses Javascript code) after all tests run:

```jspn
"script": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "posttest": "npm run lint"
}
```